# How should the path integral change under a dilation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Let's say I have a two-point function of a scalar field in flat space:

$$
\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle = \int \mathcal D  \phi \, \phi(x)\phi(y)\,e^{iS[\phi]}
$$

Then I dilate things:

$$
\langle \phi(ax)\phi(ay)\rangle = \int \mathcal D  \phi \, \phi(ax)\phi(ay)\,e^{iS[\phi]}
$$

If I field redefine $\psi(x)=\phi(ax)$ then $S[\phi] = S[\psi]$ since for the action the change to $\psi$ amounts to just a coordinate change, under which the action is invariant if constructed with the usual $d^4x\sqrt{-g}$. Meanwhile, the measure picks up a functional Jacobian:

$$
\langle \phi(ax)\phi(ay)\rangle = \int \mathcal D  \psi \, \left |\frac{\delta\phi}{\delta\psi}\right|\psi(x)\psi(y)\,e^{iS[\psi]}
$$

Given that dilations aren't a symmetry of flat space, I don't expect the two-point function to be the same after the dilation, so the Jacobian determinant shouldn't be one.

I can write

$$
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)=\psi(\tfrac{x}{a}) &= \int d^4y\,\delta^4(y-\tfrac{x}{a})\,\psi(y)\\
\implies \frac{\delta\phi(x)}{\delta\psi(y)} &=\delta^4(y-\tfrac{x}{a})
\end{align*}
$$

but then I don't know how to calculate this determinant.

Comment: I think it's simpler than that. Indeed, the 2-point function is not invariant under dilations. To see this Just notice that the field $\phi(x)$ transforms as $\phi(ax)=a^{-\Delta} \phi(x)$ so effectively your dilated two-point function differs by $a^{-2\Delta}$ form the original function.